# unable to access my sharepoint sites collection using server IP address

Tags: 2013, administration, configuration, iis, alternate-access-mapping

I am working on a SharePoint Server 2013 inside Windows Server 2008 R2.

Now some users, due to DNS limitations and network access, can not access our SharePoint sites using the server name such as `http://servername/`. Now when they try to access the sites using the server IP address such as `http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX/` then will be propted to enter username/password and they can access the home page. But when they click on one of the left navigation links which will redirect to a url such as `http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/HR/Home` they will get the following error:

[image]

Can anyone advice on this please? Why can only the home page be accessed using the IP address but not the site collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to configure IIS bindngs & Alternate Access Mappings in Central Administration for this!

Comment: Ok I added the IP address as an alternative access mapping of type "Internet" .. and now seems i am able to access the sites using IP address.. not sure about the IIS binding ,, but since users were already able to access the home page of the root site collection,, so seems IIS is configured well ... as i mentioned adding the IP inside the alternate access mapping seems allow users to access the sites,, so not sute if it is mandatory to configure IIS binding as well ????

Comment: if your server has a single ip address configured, its not mandatory... if your server has configured multiple ip addresses, you have to switch in IIS binding from "IP All unassigned" or something like that to the choosen IP for this site...

Comment: But is there a reason why i can only access the root site collection even if i did not add the IP to the alternate access mapping ?

Comment: if you type the ip in the address bar, the request goes to the server and says: hey there, is here anything listening on port 80? Your IIS says: Yes, its me... i have site with port 80 here! so you are on the root site, cauze your sharepoint is there :) Any subdirectory is "managed" by sharepoint... your IIS now - let easily say - redirects the requests to sharepoint as an application! But your SharePoint, cant handle this requests (by IP), because he is not knowing it! So you have to enter the IP in "alternate access mapping" to tell him "hey.. you have to listen on IP, too" :) thats it